# Form request contains no keys

Tags: swift, gcdwebserver

I'm attempting to use Swift to process a simple HTML form. Following the Objective-C code given in the READ ME, I cam up with the following Swift.

```
let webServer = GCDWebServer()

webServer.addDefaultHandlerForMethod("GET", requestClass: GCDWebServerRequest.self, processBlock: {request in
    return GCDWebServerDataResponse(HTML:"<html><head><title>Hello</title></head><body><form method='post' action='/' enctype='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'><input type='text' value='name'><input type='submit' value='Submit'> </form></body></html>")

})


webServer.addHandlerForMethod("POST", path: "/", requestClass: GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest.self, asyncProcessBlock: {request in

    let value = request.0 as! GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest
    //value has no keys 
})
```

I must be missing something.

Objective-C Version

```
[webServer addHandlerForMethod:@"POST"
                      path:@"/"
              requestClass:[GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest class]
              processBlock:^GCDWebServerResponse *(GCDWebServerRequest* request) {

NSString* value = [[(GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest*)request arguments] objectForKey:@"value"];
NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><p>%@</p></body></html>", value];
return [GCDWebServerDataResponse responseWithHTML:html];
}];
```

Comment: You should also add the `swift` tag and provide the original Obj-C version so people can help.

Answer (score 0):

Hrm. I admit that I was looking so closely at the Swift/Objective-C that I missed a silly thing in the HTML. I foolishly wrote...

```
value='name'
```

when it should have been...

```
name='value'
```

Cheers.